# Credential connection doesn't work

Tags: powershell, load

I'm attempting to use credential connection in a powershell script. I tried :

```
$credential = Get-Credential
```

and

```
$credential = $host.ui.PromptForCredential("Need credentials", "Please enter your user name and password.", "", "Domain")
```

But when I execute a query, I get the following message :

```
Invoke-SqlQuery -Query $Query -Server $SERVER -database $DataBase -credential $credential 
Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Login failed for user '\sa'."
\Modules\InvokeSqlQuery\InvokeSqlQuery.psm1:155 char:14
+     $cnn.Open <<<< ();
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DotNetMethodException
```

Even if I use the correct Credential, it fails. Has anyone had the same problem ?
Invoke-SqlQuery calls

```
$cnn = New-SqlConnection $Server $Database $Credential $ConnectionTimeout
```

which creates the error.

By the way, I would like to know how to load this assembly :

```
new-object [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]
New-Object : Cannot find type [[System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]]: make sure the assembly containing this type is loaded.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your second question :-), the assembly containing PSCredential is already loaded.  It is an assembly required by PowerShell. Try this:

```
$username = ConvertTo-SecureString username -AsPlainText -Force
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString pass!word -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = new-object management.automation.pscredential $username,$password
```

Comment: One neat trick to see what assemblies are loaded is `[appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()| Select ManifestModule | Sort ManifestModule`

Comment: Another trick is `[appdomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies() | Where Location | Foreach {$_.GetExportedTypes()} | Where Name -match PSCredential | Format-Table Name, Assembly -AutoSize`

Answer (score 0):

try this (PsSnapin: SqlServerCmdletSnapin100):

```
$pwd = read-host -AsSecureString -Prompt "Password"

Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query $Query -Serverinstance $SERVER -database $DataBase –Username “MyLogin” –Password $pwd
```

Comment: A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'Username'.
In fact, the allowed parameters are :
 Invoke-SqlQuery [[-Query] <String>] [-File <String>] [-Parameters <Hashtable>] [-Server <String>] [-Database <String>] [-Credential <PSCredential>] [-IncludeRecordSetIndex] [-IncludeReco
    rdsCount] [-ConnectionTimeout <Int32>] [-ExecutionTimeout <Int32>] [-WhatIf] [-Confirm] [-UseTransaction] [<CommonParameters>]

That's why I would like to instanciate a Credential.